# Can I somehow give this shortcode custom css even tho Advanced settings > Custom css says "Pro only"?

Tags: wordpress, themes

For a final assignment I need to make a website in wordpress. I'm making it using an existing theme and Elementor, a drag and drop website builder. I used a shortcode widget to get posts with the tag 'featured' displayed on the homepage.  However it doesn't look very pretty. The theme & page builder I'm using only offers custom css for those that pay for the pro version. Is there a way to work around this and maybe add css directly to a file somewhere?

This is the shortcode I use to display the posts with the 'featured' tag:

```
[display-posts tag="featured" include_date="true" date_format="F j, Y" image_size="thumbnail" include_excerpt="true" wrapper="div" posts_per_page="1"]
```

Comment: If you "inspect" (e.g. in Chrome F12 or Ctrl + Shift + I) the html produced by the shortcode you could add a style sheet that treats that html the way you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically there is an Additional CSS section in the Appearance > Customize > Additional CSS section from the admin dashboard. You can put custom CSS there.

Comment: Oh, indeed! foud it thanks!  I had found another section earlier that said custom css but that one was only for people that paid for the theme.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the child theme then put your custom CSS code to the file style.css in the child theme folder.

Simply create a child theme with this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/child-theme-generator/

Comment: Creating a child theme can be complicated, especially for a student. Try to explain in detail how and why this is an effective solution to the problem.